# Error while Connecting to MS Access Database From Android

Tags: android, android-layout, ms-access

I'm trying to retrieve data's from MS Access Database on my desktop. I didn't add any external jar file to retrieve data actually i don't know whether i have to export any external jar file  for accomplishing this.
Here is the code which i'm using to connect to Ms Access Database on my PC.

```
String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            String path="D:/MS ACCESS DATABASE/mydatabase.mdb";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver  (*.mdb)};DBQ="+path+";","","root" );
            Log.w("Connection", "open");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from tblEmp");
```

while executing this i'm getting following error on my log-cat

```
10-25 11:31:40.545: W/Error connection(422): sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

Please Help me to Solve this issue??

Comment: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver this  Driver is For Java, I think we cant use Ms Access As a Database in Android , Android provides in Pnbuilt Data base is called Sqlite

Comment: I'm not using MS Access as my Database in My Android App i just want to get the information from the access database that is located on my PC's D Drive.

Comment: @Aadi is that done your Ms access database connection

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect from Android to MS Access using Sun's JDBC-ODBC Bridge. The JDBC-ODBC Bridge from sun will only connect to a local server not a remote one. There is a commercial option from [Easysoft](http://www.easysoft.com) in there [JDBC-ODBC Bridge](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/index.html). This can connect from a Java application / applet to a remove server and then on to an MS Access ODBC data source.

Comment: Yah...i know through this way i can't access Ms-Access,because Android is not supporting ODBC ryt..But is there any other way to Connect to MS-Access. I'm able to Connect SQL-Server And Sybase by adding jtds.jdbc jar file into my project. Is There any jar file is there using that we can connect to Ms-Access.

Comment: @RichardSpencer hi i am having query http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01038.html i tried this link but it is not working for me it is giving null pointer exception